# Linking GCC C++ v4.9 application against v4.8 library results in a SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

If I understood correctly from [this document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), it isn't prohibited to link an application built with newer compiler to a library build with an older one. Also I haven't found any information regarding ABI changes between GCC 4.8 and 4.9. However, here is a small example which causes a crash (due to an invalid `vptr`, apparently):

#### lib-48.h

```
#ifndef LIB_48_H
#define LIB_48_H

struct FooBase              { virtual void foo() = 0;        };
struct FooDerived : FooBase { virtual void foo() override {} };
void boom();

#endif // LIB_48_H
```

#### lib-48.cpp

```
#include "lib-48.h"
#include <memory>

void boom() {
    auto x = std::make_shared<FooDerived>();
    x->foo();
}
```

#### app-49.cpp

```
#include "lib-48.h"
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::make_shared<FooDerived>(); // Essential to reproduce
    boom();
}
```

#### build & run

```
$ g++-4.8 -shared -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++11 lib-48.cpp -o liblib-48.so
$ g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra app-49.cpp -L. -llib-48 -Wl,-R'$ORIGIN' -o app-49
$ ./app-49 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

#### system information

Reproduced on x86_64 Ubuntu (both 14.04 and 16.04) with gcc 4.8.5 (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) and gcc version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1).

---

Note that compiling both app and lib with the same compiler makes SIGSEGV go away. So does compiling with `-O0` and few other modifications.

The question is simple: is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: " it isn't prohibited to link an application built with newer compiler to a library build with an older one" Which bit of the linked document makes you believe this?

Comment: It isn't stated clearly for my case (updated executable/old library), but: *Versioning gives subsequent releases of library binaries the ability to add new symbols and add functionality, all the while retaining compatibility with the previous releases in the series*. I hope, however, same applies to executables, not only to libraries. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to use multiple versions of GCC with only one `libstdc++` installed.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what versioning means in this context. The GCC ABI normally changes between versions, to a lesser or greater extent, so you cannot typically link libraries and executables created with different versions.

Comment: You are right, it isn't clear from this document that it is allowed. Are ABI changes documented somewhere? Where is the point when I must recompile all of my old stuff with new GCC?

Comment: Indeed, you should be able to compile the library with a newer version of GCC, and older applications will still work. That is how you can update GCC and all it's libraries without breaking previously compiled executables. But you're trying to do the reverse, and that is not guaranteed anywhere, AFAIK.

Comment: @Oleg Andriyanov as a rule of thumb, you must always compile your application *and* its dependencies with the exact same compiler. There *are* exceptions, but following that rule is usually the safest bet.